# ReactJs pass value to function in another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Login.js**

```
import FormValidation from './validation/Form' //this is Form.js

constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    submit: true,
    errorMessage: ''
  };
}

<span>{this.state.errorMessage}</span>

<label><input type="text" name="tel" onBlur={this.FormValidation.validation.phone.blur} value={this.state.telValue}/></label>
```

**Form.js**

```
let validation = {}

const FormValidation = (e) => {
  validation = {
    phone: {
      blur: (e) => {
        let v = e.target.value;
        console.log(v);
if(v.length <= 0){
    this.setState({submit: false, errorMessage: 'can not empty!'})
}
      }
    }
  }
}

export default FormValidation;
```

First I want to pass variable from `input` to `FormValidation` function to validate this input, problem is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'phone' of undefined

On line `onBlur={this.FormValidation.phone.blur}`

Second problem is I want to `setState` from `Form.js` function to `Login` compontent, as you see if length is less than zero it should make submit state to `false` and set `errorMessage` text.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: you trying to get method of a class, and not from it instance object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added comments for the problematic parts of your code :

```
// FormValidation is a function, but in your input you are using it as an object.
const FormValidation = (e) => {
    validation = {
        phone: {
            blur: (e) => {
                let v = e.target.value;
                console.log(v);
                if (v.length <= 0) {
                    // FormValidation is not a React component, so it doesn't have a state. You should just return the error:
                    // return {submit: false, errorMessage: 'can not empty!'}
                    this.setState({submit: false, errorMessage: 'can not empty!'})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

export default FormValidation;
```

Here is what you could do instead:
**Login.js**

```
import FormValidation from './validation/Form' //this is Form.js

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        submit: true,
        errorMessage: '',
        telValue: ''
    };

    handleBlur = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value
        const validationError = FormValidation.validation.phone.blur(value)
        if (validationError) {
            this.setState({
                submit: validationError.submit,
                errorMessage: validationError.errorMessage
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                telValue: value
            })
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <label>
                <span>
                    {this.state.errorMessage}
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="tel" onBlur={this.handleBlur} value={this.state.telValue}/>
            </label>
        )
    }
}
```

**Form.js**

```
let validation = {}



const FormValidation = {
    validation = {
        phone: {
            blur: (value) => {
                console.log(value);
                if (value.length <= 0) {
                    return {submit: false, errorMessage: 'can not empty!'}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

export default FormValidation;
```

Comment: Thanks,  just one thing, by your answer I need to set multiple handler to pass variable to validation, I looking for a cleaner way, so is there a way to pass a string to handler then pass to class? like `onBlur={this.handleBlur(this,'phone')}`